# Strongly-typed partial view is not loading from jQuery function on radio button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two strongly-typed partial views (Developers list and Testers list) and the respective views are Developers.ascx and Testers.ascx

Now I want to load one partial view based on the radio button selected.
The below code is not loading the URL that I specified on radio button change.

Code Snippet:

$(':radio').click(function() {

```
alert(this.value);
var url = '/Home/Developers/';
if (this.value == '2') {                 
     url = '/Home/Testers/';
}

 $(".Inquiries").load(url);
```

});

I would appreciate if anyone can provide a code snippet to load strongly-typed partial view from jQuery.

Thanks

Rita

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have separate Developers and Testers actions on your Home controller?

Comment: I don't have. I m not sure what code that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code sample worked fine for me, I think the problem is either you need to add it inside of a document ready function or it might be you need to include the file name

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(':radio').click(function() {
  alert(this.value);
  var url = '/Home/Developers/Developers.ascx';
  if (this.value == '2') {
   url = '/Home/Testers/Testers.ascx';
  }
  $(".Inquiries").load(url);
 });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I will go with a generic answer that will help you in many situations - [get FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com/), and

- on Net pane check that request is sent, and what is the answer from the server
- on Scripts pane set breakpoints in your script to see if its called
- on Console pane do both check js errors and ajax calls
- and so on

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue until i used lambda expression on Html.DisplayFor:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UnitPrice)
```